# Prism Navigation is not working correctly

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I just created a sample Android-XAMRIN project using Prism Template Pack. My base project in dot net standard 2.0 and I am using Prism.Unity.Forms 7.2.0.1367. While launching application it is showing blank page. I am attaching all images of project pages. [AndroidProjProp.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kB3y.png)
[App_xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqvuL.png) [App_xaml_cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuJ2z.png)
[App_Proj_Prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nho07.png) [MainActivity_cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZBdI.png) [MainPageViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynjy5.png) [Nuget_Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poEJt.png) [ViewModelBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIhFY.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as images, but textual. Posting code as images makes the question less searchable and less accessible.

Comment: Furthermore the code of your `MainView` is mising and so is a screenshot of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow Brian Lagunas's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81Q2fxFWIqA) to create your app.

I followed his tutorial to createa a sample project, and run on my device, the result is showing a text `Welcome to Xamarin Forms and Prism!` .

The code of `MainPage.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BlankApp2.Views.MainPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms and Prism!" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**Note**

1.The difference is that we choose  the value of `container` is `Unity`,just as follows：
[image]

2. Since it is a Xamarin Forms app,so we create user interfaces in XAML with code-behind in C#. and these interfaces are rendered as performant native controls on each platform. So the project pages is coded with format of `XAML`,not `Activity`(`MainActivity`) just as you mentioned.

For more information about Xamarin Forms, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin-forms

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I followed the same approach. I created using Prism Template. Here everything is automatic. We no need to do anything. Without Prism it is working fine. I can see some text on page. But once Prism Template is used to create it is not working. Only a blank page appear without any text.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you by the words `But once Prism Template is used to create` . Could you please post more details about it? How did you do it?

Comment: 1. Open Visual studio 2017. Under File->New Project then Prism/Xamarin.Forms. 2. Now choose Prism Blank App (Xamarin.Forms).  3. Now Prism Project Wizard appears asking for container unity or dry loc. 4. Select unity and Done. 5. Now build the project and run. It is showing totally blank page.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't have such a problem following your steps .I  tested on OS win10 and visual 2017/2019.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this was happening due to the current version of VS2017. I was using. I updated visual studio and it is working fine. Thanks